# Passing objects to a JAX WS

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, webservices-client

I am highlighting one scenario in which a web service’s method with a java.lang.Object as a parameter can’t be invoked.

I am using Netbeans 7.1 with Tomcat 7.

For creating, deploying and accessing the web service, I followed the steps given at :
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/

**The web service endpoint is as follows :**

```
package com.metrows;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

/**
 *
 * @author 298790
 */
@WebService(serviceName = "NewWebService")
public class NewWebService {

    /**
     * This is a sample web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
        return "Hello " + txt + " !";
    }

    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "sendObjParam")
    public Object sendObjParam(@WebParam(name = "paramObj") Object paramObj) {
        //TODO write your implementation code here:
       System.out.println("In NewWebService.sendObjParam(...) "+paramObj);

       return paramObj;
    }

/**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "passCustomParams")
    @Oneway
    public void passCustomParams(@WebParam(name = "tenant") Tenant tenant) {

        System.out.println("In NewWebService.passCustomParams(...) : tenant = " + tenant);

        System.out.println(": " + tenant.getMap());
    }

}
```

**The Tenant is as follows :**

```
package com.valueobjects;

import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 *
 * @author 298790
 */
public class Tenant {

    private String tenantId;
    private String tenantName;
    private HashMap map;

    public String getTenantId() {
        return tenantId;
    }

    public void setTenantId(String tenantId) {
        this.tenantId = tenantId;
    }

    public String getTenantName() {
        return tenantName;
    }

    public void setTenantName(String tenantName) {
        this.tenantName = tenantName;
    }

    public HashMap getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(HashMap map) {
        this.map = map;
    }


}
```

**The client is as follows :**

```
package metro_ws_client;

/**
 *
 * @author 298790
 */
public class Metro_WS_Client {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println(hello("Aao Thakur !!!"));

        Tenant tenant = new Tenant();
        tenant.setTenantId("lnt");
        tenant.setMap(new Tenant.Map());

        passCustomParams(tenant);
        Object o = new Object();
        //String s = "Shot";
        sendObjParam(o);
    }


    private static String hello(java.lang.String name) {
        metro_ws_client.NewWebService_Service service = new metro_ws_client.NewWebService_Service();
        metro_ws_client.NewWebService port = service.getNewWebServicePort();
        return port.hello(name);
    }

    private static Object sendObjParam(java.lang.Object paramObj) {
        com.metrows.NewWebService_Service service = new com.metrows.NewWebService_Service();
        com.metrows.NewWebService port = service.getNewWebServicePort();
        return port.sendObjParam(paramObj);
    }

private static void passCustomParams(com.metrows.Tenant tenant) {
        com.metrows.NewWebService_Service service = new com.metrows.NewWebService_Service();
        com.metrows.NewWebService port = service.getNewWebServicePort();
        port.passCustomParams(tenant);
    }
}
```

During server start-up, I get the following exceptions(not the full stack trace as it is repetitive) :

```
WARNING: Unable to load class [com.sun.codemodel.JArrayClass$1] to check against the @HandlesTypes annotation of one or more ServletContentInitializers. 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.codemodel.JArrayClass$1
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2006)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1969)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1858)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1826)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1812)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1306)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:896)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5103)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1329)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:389)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:621)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
Feb 13, 2012 4:46:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig checkHandlesTypes
WARNING: Unable to load class [com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel$1] to check against the @HandlesTypes annotation of one or more ServletContentInitializers. 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel$1
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2006)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1969)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1858)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1826)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1812)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1306)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:896)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5103)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1329)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:389)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:621)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
Feb 13, 2012 4:46:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig checkHandlesTypes
WARNING: Unable to load class [com.sun.codemodel.JExpr$3] to check against the @HandlesTypes annotation of one or more ServletContentInitializers. 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.codemodel.JExpr$3
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2006)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1969)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1858)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1826)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1812)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1306)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:896)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5103)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1329)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:389)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:621)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
```

***Now the call to the web method ‘hello’ is successful but when invocation of ‘sendObjParam’ gives the following exception; also, not able to create a java.util.Map in the client and set it in the tenant object***  :

```
Hello Aao Thakur !!! !
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:185)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:83)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:587)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:546)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:531)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:428)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:211)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
    at $Proxy32.sendObjParam(Unknown Source)
    at metro_ws_client.Metro_WS_Client.sendObjParam(Metro_WS_Client.java:35)
    at metro_ws_client.Metro_WS_Client.main(Metro_WS_Client.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.AnyTypeBeanInfo.serializeURIs(AnyTypeBeanInfo.java:138)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:665)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:141)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:321)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:687)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:263)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.BridgeImpl.marshal(BridgeImpl.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.Bridge.marshal(Bridge.java:130)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:310)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:249)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:144)
    ... 14 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Please guide me as to how I can pass standard java objects – concrete or interface, custom objects with non-primitive members to a Web service ?

Comment: When you use webservices it means you will have an XML representation of your object, in other words a string representation. If youre not using primitives (which SOAP supports), what kind of string representation do you expect to have? in the java world i can only think of serialization, is this what you expect?

Answer (score 2):

The objects you are passing into the web service client methods need to be serializable by JAXB. At a bare minimum this means they need to be annotated with `@XMLRootElement`. Which of course means that you can't pass in a `new Object()` (which is hardly useful anyway).